# handling LARGE dataset

Tags: database, dataset, large-data-volumes

What is the best solution for handling LARGE dataset.
I have txt files broken down into multiple files. 
which if I add up it will be about 100 GB
the files are nothing more than just

uniqID1 uniqID2
etc

id pairs 
and if I want calculate things like 
1:unique number of uniqIDs etc 
2:list of other IDs uniqID1 is linked to?

what is the best solution? 
how do I update these into a database?

thank you!

Comment: You have not really described your problem well enough for any suggestion to be made. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

So if you had a table with the following columns:

```
           id1 varchar(10)   // how long are you ids? are they numeric? text?
           id2 varchar(10)
```

with about five billion rows in the table, and you wanted quick answers to questions such as:

```
        how many unique values in column id1 are there?
        what is the set of distinct values from id1 where id2 = {some parameter}
```

a relational database (that supports SQL) and a table with an index on id1 and another index on id2 would do what you need.  SQLite would do the job.

EDIT: to import them it would be best to separate the two values with some character that never occurs in the values, like a comma or a pipe character or a tab, one pair per line:

```
         foo|bar
         moo|mar
```

EDIT2: You don't need relational but it doesn't hurt anything, and your data structure is more extensible if the db is relational.